# Cloning object in returnValue using a PHPUnit Mock

Tags: php, phpunit

I am mocking a method from a class that looks like this:

```
class Employee { 

/**
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getEmploymentBegin()
{
    return clone $this->employmentBegin;
}
```

My mock looks like:

```
$employee = $this->getMockBuilder('\MyApp\Employee')->disableOriginalConstructor()->getMock();

$employee
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getEmploymentBegin')
        ->will($this->returnValue(date_create('05.11.2012')));
```

Later the code that I am testing needs to manipulate the date:

```
$a= $this->employee->getEmploymentBegin();
$b = $this->employee->getEmploymentBegin();
$b->modify('+ 6 weeks')->modify('yesterday');
```

**My issue is** that at the end Both `$a` and `$b` end-up with the same reference.

Comment: Aren't they one and the same instance. It seems for me like `$obj = clone Class()`, `$start = $obj`, `$end = $obj`, `$end->setId(1)`.

Comment: `Employee` is only one class. I am trying to clone `DateTime` instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like using `returnCallback()` did the job.

```
    $employee
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getEmploymentBegin')
        ->will($this->returnCallback(
            function () { return date_create('05.11.2012'); }
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your mock to:

```
$date = date_create('05.11.2012');
$employee
    ->expects($this->any())
    ->method('getEmploymentBegin')
    ->will($this->onConsecutiveCalls(clone $date, clone $date));
```

---

The `clone` seems like an important implementation detail. I'm not sure how to deal with that. Maybe `getEmploymentBegin` should return a simple type (like a string). Anything that wants to do date arithmetic can then upgrade it to a `Date`.

Comment: I think assigning vars to the cloned object does not make any more clones :)

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: The OP's decision to have start and end reffering to the method that is supposed to clone might not result into clones?

Comment: That is irrelevant. If you changed `$end` to `$start2` the conceptual problem disappears but the reference issue remains. The mock _must_ provide a clone to ensure it works as the original does. I think that this is a problem you don't want to have since it introduces complexity in the wrong places, hence the suggestion to downgrade the values to simple types.

Comment: I think I get the point. Thanks. But maybe it's not possible everytime to write your classes to not use whole objects, but parts of them?

Comment: Thanks. I had nightmares in the past in representing dates as strings. Regarding the solution, is no good because the method itself is called `n` times ...